# Can I access Azure AppFabric Cache from development emulator?

Tags: azure, appfabric, azure-caching

I am getting below exception when I access Azure cache from my dev azure application.

> ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure.
>   Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are
>   unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For
>   on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions.
>   Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client
>   account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed
>   through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the
>   server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size
>   sent from the client.)

Is there any restriction that the Azure cache can only be accessed from hosted Azure application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have no issue accessing AppFabric Cache from the emulator. Just note that the cache is only in Windows Azure itself; there's no emulated cache running locally.

Do you have any further detail on the error message? Also, are you accessing it directly in code? Using it as a session state provider?

Comment: The issue was with my net connection .There was a firewall blocking..When I tried from another internet connection I was able to access the Azure AppFabric cache from emulator.

Comment: In fact, you don't even need to be running the emulator. You can access the Windows Azure Shared Cache directly from IIS Express, as long as your web.config has the right settings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can access Azure AppFabric cache from emulators. Just want to configure correctly and there should be no firewall blocking