# SQL Azure multiple instances web role :- session not working on local machine

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

We are hosting our web application over azure. Everything went well so far with a web role of only 1 small instance.

We then decided to try out 2 x extra small instances for our web role so that http requests will be load balanced.

Our session is also stored using the MS recommended method found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg457897) .

When we published on the production environment, the session work well (being filled an all). When testing it locally on the azure emulator, the session just wont be filled.

Anyone know what might be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: AppFabric Cache doesn't actually have an emulator-relevant mode.  When you are running in development, you are still connecting to the live AppFabric Cache and need appropriate firewall setup to connect.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181767/can-i-access-azure-appfabric-cache-from-development-emulator.

Comment: What kind of error message did you get when running on Azure Emulator?

Comment: I am not getting any azure related error messages. Im only experiencing errors related to empty sessions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the local firewall. Turning it off made the cache available for session state!

Comment: Storing your development session state in your production cache may not be a great idea. For development you should probably just use InProc or StateServer cache.